# Did SO recently start using Google APIs?

Tags: support, browser-support

I have used SO at work for almost 2 years now without problem. Last week, I started getting a red banner across the top saying javascript from an external server was being blocked. My IT guys said Google APIs are "very malware prone security risks", and they have blocked those for a long time. Because I just started having this problem, their conclusion was SO must have just recently started using them, and so I was out of luck, ticket closed. No more SO as a work resource for me.

Is this anywhere near true? Is there something else that might be causing that red banner to pop up?

Comment: SO has used the Google CDN for a very long time. Your IT guys may want to review their policy. (imo their reason is moronic)

Comment: No arguments from me on the lack of love for my IT guys. I just can't reopen the trouble ticket unless I can point to something else that might be causing it.

Comment: They switched to using Google Ads a month ago or so. But that should be independent of the working of the other scripts. Also it would immensely help if you could open a dev console and share which scripts fail to load.

Comment: also see [What else do I need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100)

Comment: `jquery.min.js` and `analytics.js` comes from google servers, which raises the question of why we're still needing jquery on a site targetted at developers but that's a different disucssion. It would be easier to have an opinion here if we knew what exactly is being blocked, like rene said.

Comment: @ivarni didn't they [drop everything else and use jQuery instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/158100)?

Comment: It has been going on for quite some time, and as another SO user who works in a place where google apis are blocked, I find this extremely annoying.

Comment: You probably only started having the problem recently because those resources cache for a while. If you can flip on a vpn or physically move the machine to a location where google apis are allowed to let the browser load the jquery, you should be set for a while.

Comment: Just deploy the file somewhere else under the same URL and change your `.hosts` file. Sounds like less hassle :)

Comment: For the record, we noticed in our offices the issue of `ajax.googleapis.com/` being required on StackOverflow **starting November 30th 2017**. We didn't raise the issue on meta because we thought it was the Great Firewall of China. But you're in Nebraska, so it's now likely also an issue from StackOverflow itself.

Comment: @Cœur that's about the timeframe my problems started. Did you ever find a solution? Is this stuff saved in internet temp files or something I can get at home and move to work? I'm out of my expertise here.

Comment: @Stijn There are valid reasons not to allow Google CDNs (or any other CDN, for that matter). Mainly privacy is a concern (in fact, there are talks inside the EU to ban loading of external resources), since Google can easily use their CDN to create profiles of users. Yes, the reasons as given are moronic, but try to explain how that tracking works to the average employee - "its prone to malware" is easy to understand (its bad), and thus sometimes the best you can do.

Comment: That's odd @Cœur, I've had to whitelist `ajax.googleapis.com` in NoScript for a couple of years at least.

Comment: @Polygnome: exactly. I would imagine that Google and other CDN providers would use usage data to enhance their advertising and search intelligence data, but who can say where the privacy boundaries are these days?

Comment: @halfer Sadly, too few users are aware of these issues. fortunately the EU is already discussing wether or not to forbid these practices (much like the dual click solution needed for social networks for german websites). So I hope that in the coming years, most service providers will - at least for the european market - have to obey more strict guidlines for data protection.

Comment: See also [what value do we actually get from the CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133810/134300)?

Comment: @Polygnome: the German proposal sounds interesting, but I wonder if that won't fly - there would be too much industry opposition to make it workable (the EU Cookie law was well-intended, and yet it was mostly implementers who resisted it, seeing it just as a source of extra work). However, if we can require companies to use privacy-friendly CDNs, that would be perfectly okay - I think outsourcing CDNs is fine in itself.

Comment: What probably happened for the OP is that their cache for 1 of the Google APIs resource expired, (that only happens once a year), and the first time the OP used SO was before OP's firewall started blocking it

Comment: Shouldn't SO fallback to using a local copy of any external resource anyway? If a CDN goes down (however unlikely) then that should be a fallback.

Answer (score 19):

I'm facing the same problem in China (the evil government has blocked *all* of Google).

My solution is a plugin (I use Google Chrome), [Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii). I downloaded a copy of that JS with VPN and put it in a constant directory in my computer. Then I configured Resource Override to replace the request to Google AJAX Library with my own copy of the script, then everything starts working well.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not affiliated with that plugin in any way, it's recommended by peers in my school. I share it here on Meta Stack Overflow only because I think it's useful for me and may potentially be useful to anyone else.

Comment: An alternative for Firefox might be [PourBico](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pourbico/) (not affiliated). It's not Quantum compatible though, in Quantum you could probably use userscripts to achieve this.

Comment: [Decentraleyes](https://decentraleyes.org) emulate the most common cdn, works with Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 6):

I think the `ajax.googleapis.com` domain has been in use on Stack Overflow for a long time - I have had to whitelist it in NoScript for a couple of years at least.

For me, this just fetches the following resource:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

What you could do, if googleapis.com is blocked completely for you, is to alias this in your local hosts file to `127.0.0.1`, and then get your development machine to host a copy of this file using IIS or Apache, including the full directory path.

Since Stack Overflow is now an HTTPS site, you'd also need to generate a self-signed certificate, and get your browser to trust that.

There does not seem to be any markup verification (using JS file hashes) that would prevent this working, so it might be worth a try.

---

Or, if that sounds like a lot of hassle, you could bring in a tablet computer with your own internet connection, and just use Stack Overflow on that. However, you'd lose the ability to easily copy+paste between SO and your editor, so I'd personally go with the first option.

Comment: would `172.217.9.170 ajax.googleapis.com` work as well or not? (not in office to try right now)

Comment: @Cœur: it depend on Google's configuration, and my guess would be no - even if that points to another copy that is for some unusual reason not blocked by the OP's firewall, I would imagine it would be brittle. Google would likely detect the anomaly automatically and block it as a possible unknown security threat. It is probably just more reliable to self-host.

Comment: Only adding to the hosts file isn't enough, you also need to generate a fake ssl certificate and import it

Comment: Good point @Ferrybig, added.

Comment: Yes, `googleapis.com` has been listed on *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)* (near *"The following sites should be accessible"*) for many years (since rev. 7, 2011-04-25).